# Using malloc to initialize char *vals[SIZE] in a struct

Tags: c, struct, malloc

I have a struct like this:

```
struct students {
    char *names[MAXLENGTH];
};
```

How would I initialize the struct using `malloc`?

I tried

```
struct students student1 = {malloc(MAXLENGTH * sizeof(char**))};
```

but that gave me a "missing braces around initializer" error.

I'm new to C, so I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: `{malloc(MAXLENGTH * sizeof(char**))}`.. In this, this `{` is required..?? I mean try with `(`... Let me know the results..

Comment: It now says "error: invalid initializer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can allocate an instance of the struct like this:

```
struct students *pStudent = malloc(sizeof *pStudent);
```

This will allocate the array of string pointers (since it's part of the `struct students`), but not set the pointers to point at anything (their values will be undefined).

You need to set each individual string pointer, for instance like so:

```
pStudent->names[0] = "unwind";
```

This stores a pointer to a literal string. You can also allocate memory dynamically:

```
pStudent->names[1] = malloc(20);
strcpy(pStudent->names[1], "unwind");
```

of course, if you `malloc()` space you must remember to `free()` it. Don't mix literal strings with dynamically allocated ones, since it becomes impossible to know which ones need `free()`ing.

Comment: @user2281820 I don't know, it seems whoever did that has removed the downvote, since.

Comment: Buddy, don't use strcpy, and don't teach strcpy. I know the size is fixed (20), but use a safer string function with the fixed size.

Answer (score 1):

This is totally wrong `struct students student1 = {malloc(MAXLENGTH * sizeof(char**))};`

Try this code.

```
struct students* Student1 = malloc(sizeof(struct students ));
Student1->names[0] = malloc(sizeof(NAME_MAX));
scanf("%s",Student1->names[0]);//It may be first name. I think you want like this .
```

Comment: -1, your field accesses are wrong, you can't use `.` on a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a for loop like this :

```
#define MAX_NAME_LENGTH 20

struct student s;
for(int i = 0; i < MAXLENGTH; ++i)
{
    s.names[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_NAME_LENGTH);
}
```